# How to make the ReactJS App to navigate to some pages from outside the app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a very basic `ReactJS` app:

- [[Demo]](https://react-testing-routes-navigate-outside.stackblitz.io)
- [[Source]](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-testing-routes-navigate-outside?file=public%2Findex.html)

Where I want to make the App to navigate to some pages from outside the app (without reloading the web page, I mean, something similar to when the app does: `this.props.history.push(...)`).

**/public/index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#link_page1').click(function(){
    console.log('Navigating the app to: Page1...');
    // @TODO
  });
  $('#link_page2').click(function(){
    console.log('Navigating the app to: Page2...');
    // @TODO
  });
  $('#link_page3').click(function(){
    console.log('Navigating the app to: Page3...');
    // @TODO
  });
});
</script>

<div id="root"></div>

<div>
  <h3>From outside the App, move the App to:</h3>
  <button id="link_page1">Page1</button>
  <button id="link_page2">Page2</button>
  <button id="link_page3">Page3</button>
</div>
```

**/src/App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Page1 from './pages/Page1';
import Page2 from './pages/Page2';
import Page3 from './pages/Page3';
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Page1 } />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2 } />
        <Route path="/page3" component={Page3 } />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

If you want, you can fork the `stackblitz` above, apply your approach, and then paste the new link back here.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `a` (anchor) tag with `href` to the desired location? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp or if you want to do it through js, use `window.location` to assign a new url? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: those approches will reload the web page and I don't want that. Thank you, though.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case you can use `history.pushState` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState which is what the `history` package (depended on by `react-router-dom`) uses under the hood

Comment: I tried: `history.pushState({}, null, '/page2');` with no success. You can try it by yourself with the following link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-testing-routes-navigate-outside-ljbc1994?file=public/index.html, maybe you can fork that, apply your approach, and then paste the new link back here. Thanks!

Comment: Here you go, create a custom history object and attach to window so it can be used outside of the app  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-testing-routes-navigate-outside-ljbc1994-9evmr3?file=src%2Findex.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `react-router-dom` you can create a history object (using the `history` package) and pass this to the `Router` component. Therefore if you create the history object like so and attach this to the window then pass the created history to the `App` component:

```
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from "history";

const customHistory = createHistory();
window.customHistory = customHistory;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App history={customHistory} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

In the app.js component:

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App({ history }) {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Page1 } />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2 } />
        <Route path="/page3" component={Page3 } />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Now you can use that `history` object to change the page outside of the application:

```js
$('#link_page2').click(function() {
  console.log('Navigating the app to: Page1...');
  window.customHistory.push("/page2");
});
```

Comment: I just did that, you can check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-testing-routes-navigate-outside-ljbc1994?file=src%2Findex.js, but when you click on the links (even on the ones that were working before), they don't work (the app is showing nothing, like it is no matching any route). Could you please, fork that last code, check by yourself and post back here a working version? Thanks!

Comment: You're using `history@^5.0.0`, you need to use `history@^4.9.0` which is used by `react-router-dom`. Then, it'll work.

Comment: you was totally right. I tried downgrading to version `4.9.0` and it worked great. Thank you a lot.